# How to extract parts from regex in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

How to extract parts from regex in C++?

For example I have patterns like this:

```
new line means "followed by"

delimiter string,
name,
':' character,
list of Xs, where X is name; (string followed by ';' character)
```

I can use regex for matching, but is there a way to not only match,
but also extract parts from the pattern? For example:

```
$DatasetName: A; B; C;
```

is a given string, and I would like to extract the dataset name,
and then the column names A, B, and C.

Comment: Have you looked at the example code [on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match)? And additionally, are you using `std::regex` or a different regex implementation?

Comment: Are  you sure you need regex?  Perhaps you simply need to parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as already suggested you could do by hand parsing similar to this (it is only for demonstration purposes and does not claim to be perfect):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

bool parse_by_hand(const std::string& phrase)
{
    enum parse_state
    {
        parse_name,
        parse_value,
    };
    std::string name, current_value;
    std::vector<std::string> values;
    parse_state state = parse_name;
    for(std::string::const_iterator iterator = phrase.begin(); iterator != phrase.end(); iterator++)
    {
        switch(state)
        {
        case parse_name:
            if(*iterator != ':')
                name += *iterator;
            else 
                state = parse_value;
            break;
        case parse_value:
            if(*iterator != ';')
                current_value += *iterator;
            else 
            {
                state = parse_value;
                values.push_back(current_value);
                current_value.clear();
            }
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
    // Error checking here, name parsed? values parsed?
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string phrase("$DatasetName: A; B; C;");
    parse_by_hand(phrase);
}
```

As for the `std::regex`, my first shot was for something like this `([^:]*):(([^;]*);)*` but unless I'm not mistaken (and I hope someone corrects me if I am), the recursive capture group will give you the last matched value not all values so you would still have to do multiple iterations with `regex_search` which takes away the ease of 'one-liner-regex-matching' off the table. Alternatively if `std::regex` is not a must and you can use Boost, take a look at [Repeated captures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/regex/doc/captures.html), this should solve the capture group issue.